# problem with jinja2 autoescape in google app engine webapp

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I decided to install jinja2 to use with my webapp application in order to support the autoescape functionality. So I installed jinja2 into python 2.5 and created a symlink within my project to point to that directory. It's mostly working fine.

EXCEPT, when I actually try to use the {% autoescape true %} tag, I get the message:

```
File "/Users/me/project/templates/_base.html", line 1, in template
    {% autoescape true %}
TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'autoescape'.
```

I'm using the tags as they have it in the docs:

```
{% autoescape true %} stuff {{var1}} stuff {{var2}}{% endautoescape %}
```

Within my handler file I'm importing the relevant stuff:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader, TemplateNotFound
from jinja2.ext import autoescape
```

And the import is working fine because it's not throwing an error. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a problem with jinja2 itself, like maybe in ext.py?

---

UPDATE:
I tried sharth's suggestion below and got the same result. Here is my updated handler using his suggestion.

```
class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):

        self.context['testEscape']='<script type="javascript">alert("hi");</script>'
        env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader([os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')]), autoescape=False)
        template = env.get_template('index.html')
        content = template.render(self.context)
        self.response.out.write(content)
```

Again, it works fine as long as I don't use the autoescape tag.

Comment: I just noticed that the jinja2 autocomplete tag doesn't work as documented in the tipfy framework either. Which leads me to think it's a bug in jinja2, not an issue with how I'm using it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `{% autoescape %}` tag needs Jinja 2.4 or higher and the `jinja2.ext.autoescape` extension loaded.

```
env = Environment(autoescape=True, extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
                  loader=...)
```

Comment: Thank you. I had thought I could just import the extension with the import statement at the top of the script and didn't realize I needed to set the extension as a parameter when I instantiated the Environment. I suppose the paragraph at the top of the documentation for extensions (http://jinja.pocoo.org/extensions/) with the title "Adding Extensions" should have been a dead giveaway. :-)

Comment: actually what is the meaning of autoescape and why use ?