# Can't disable the autoescape in jinja2

Tags: google-app-engine, escaping, jinja2

In GAE I use jinja2 with the autoescape, and everything works well.

```
import jinja2
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape = True)
```

In one template I don't want the autoescape, so I tried to disable it like this:

```
{% autoescape false %}
{{content}}
{% endautoescape %}
```

When it's time to render this template I get the message `Encountered unknown tag 'autoescape'.`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674366/problem-with-jinja2-autoescape-in-google-app-engine-webapp

Comment: I checked that post earlier, but I have a different problem: the escaping for me works always and I can't disable it (rather than not working as in the other post)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
{{ content | safe}}
```

docs:

- [Flask — Controlling Autoescaping](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#controlling-autoescaping)
- [Jinja2 — Filters — safe](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#safe)

Comment: We have found this doubles execution build time.

Answer (score 6):

In order for the `autoescape` tag to be recognized, you need to enable the autoescape extension when setting up jinja2, like this:

```
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                               autoescape = True,
                               extensions = ['jinja2.ext.autoescape'])
```

Also, make sure you're using jinja2 version 2.4 or higher in your app.yaml (the [current version is GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27) is 2.6):

```
libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
```

For more information, see [the documentation for the autoescape extension](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/extensions/#autoescape-extension).

Comment: it does not work for me in jinja 3.0 : AttributeError: module 'jinja2.ext' has no attribute 'autoescape'