# Does jinja2 have filter help show only part of variable in browser

Tags: jinja2

If I use

```
{{ post.body_html | safe }}
```

program will select data from MySQL and display on browser as complete article.
So does jinja2 have filter help  show part of variable like article's first paragraph.

Comment: This can be done using the backend!

Comment: Check this answer out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257138/cant-disable-the-autoescape-in-jinja2

Comment: Also, can you post a mock up of what the post object would like look.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `truncate()` filter. You can send to it as argument the number of characters you want to show in your template:

```
{{ post.body_html | truncate(40) | safe }}
```

Obviously you can code a function (in your python file) which detects the first paragraph, counts the number of characters and send this number (that it returns) to your `truncate()` filter in your template.